Как обратиться к динамически созданному lineEdit?
Есть проблема, вот я динамически создал line edit. Но как мне теперь к нему обратиться??Например чтобы поместить его содержимое в переменную.
QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
layout->addWidget(lineEdit);

Если объявить имя то непонятно как к нему обратиться. Через ui->"Имя лайн эдита".text(); не сработает.
QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
lineEdit->setObjectName("lineEdit_" + QString::number(counter));
layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
counter++;


Обратиться откуда? через lineEdit->text() почему не подходит?

Потому что lineEdit->text(); возвращает "".

Почему ожидается, что он вернёт что-то отличное? Если это свежесозданный виджет и ничем не наполненный.

Я вывел его на экран и жду что пользователь введет в него значение и я положу его в переменную. Как сделать динамический массив переменных я знаю. А как взять значение из динамически созданных lineEdit нет.

@RazorRazor, переменную объявляй в заголовке, создавай в конструкторе. в любой функции класса будет видна. в чем проблема?

@Ingvar проблема была не в том что переменная была вне зоны видимости функции, а в том что я не мог создать в окне несколько lineEdit'ов и потом к ним обращаться чтобы брать из них данные. Я уже опубликов ответ на свой вопрос.

@RazorRazor, дружище, в том то и дело, что исходя из вопроса я и дал ответ. Но в своем ответе (в коде) Вы не удосужились упомянуть, что создаете их несколько! И даже в коде решения Ваши мысли покрыты мраком. Тут нет телепатов - описывайте Ваши проблемы более подробно и четко.

@Ingvar впервые задаю вопрос, если плохо описал, извиняюсь.

Как я понял из комментариев, задачу можно решить, если выполнить подписку на изменение данных пользователем. Например, через привязку лямбды к сигналу textChanged:
connect(lineEdit , &QLineEdit::textChanged, [this](const QString& text) {
    // использовать text как новый текст, введённый пользователем
});


У меня удалось решить проблему таким образом:
1)Создаем динамический массив std::vector<QLineEdit*> veclineEdits;
2)Создаем и добавляем в окно lineEdit
3)Сохраняем lineEdit в созданный массив veclineEdits
После этого имеется доступ ко всем созданным lineEdit через массив и их можно использовать(например я вывожу в qDebug() то что у меня написано в lineEdit с индексом i который я ввожу в lineEdit заранее определенном)



В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в Справке.
